# Remove ubuntu-desktop

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, software-uninstall

I've installed xubuntu-desktop and I want to get rid of all the ubuntu-desktop and Unity-related packages. But all the guides I've found are either outdated (psychocatz) or simply don't work (aptitude). What can I do to remove all the ubuntu-desktop packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove Unity as answered on our forum by Dennis:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-\* unity-scope-\* unity-webapps-\* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6\* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps\* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt\* overlay-scrollbar\* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration gnome-control-center gnome-session
```

Comment: Anyone try this in regular Ubuntu? As I count Unity completely worthless for non-touch devices, it'd be great to free up the disk space. But don't want to bork the install.

Comment: I haven't tried it.

Comment: Tried on 14.04.3 LTS, works as advertised